# Best/Fastest Way to Test Python CGI locally?

Tags: python, cgi

Just wondering whats the best way to test Python CGI while developing a site?
(I'm used to PHP for web dev so bear with me :P)

Comment: see also [Minimal http server for testing cgi-bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886483/minimal-http-server-for-testing-cgi-bin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Python standard library's [CGIHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/library/cgihttpserver.html) module is a simple, quick-and-dirty way to locally test CGI scripts!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of Python web frameworks which make this easier for you.  Django, for example, has a built-in web server designed for testing out your application.

However, if you're already using CGI, the easiest way to test it would be to run Apache.  Configuring CGI for Apache is straightforward and there is a lot of good documentation.