# Minimal http server for testing cgi-bin

Tags: linux, httpserver, cgi-bin

I have developed and maintain a web application which acts as a front end for some scrips in cgi-bin which in turn call C programs on the server. The web server is Apache2, hosted both on my office **Linux** box for testing and on Amazon ECC for the real deployment.

My problem is that I'm off travelling, mostly without any internet connection and with only a small portable linux machine, yet I want to develop the next release of the web pages, scripts, data sets and programs. Testing static web pages is no issue but testing pages which call server-side cgi-bin scripts is always problematic, so my idea is to put a minimal http server on the portable linux box (ubuntu 14.04) which will allow the server and client to be on the same machine without any internet (and maybe with just a socket) in-between.

Of course I can and do test scripts and programs directly, but this does not exercise features such as handling top-bit set characters in $POST_DATA or setting and retrieving cookies so would inevitably result in some divergence of code-base.

So:

1. Is this way sensible or is there a better or simpler means to do what I want?
2. If it is sensible, what hppt server would you recommend? I thought of miniWeb but have no experience of it.

PS: I'm expert in the the (maths of the) server-side programs but have much less experience as an apache sysadmin.

Comment: Lighty maybe? http://www.lighttpd.net

Comment: you can use python to start a minimal cgi enabled webserver, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30516779/906489

Answer (score 1):

For many things this is sufficient:

```
python3 -mhttp.server --cgi
```

Unfortunately, it's so minimal, that it doesn't support stuff like setting the HTTP Status: https://bugs.python.org/issue10487

I'm not using lighttpd because I don't want to have to write a configuration file. Another minimal server that can be used is mini-httpd:

```
sudo apt install mini-httpd
/usr/sbin/mini_httpd -D -p 8000 -c 'cgi-bin/*'
```

The `-D` option keeps the server in the foreground instead of daemonizing it. The `-p` option is the port and `-c` is a pattern for my cgi scripts.

I also found that the built-in webserver of `busybox` can handle cgi scripts just fine:

```
busybox httpd -p 8000 -f
```

Note that the executable scripts need to be in the `cgi-bin` folder of the "home" directory (defaults to the current directory, set with `-h <DIR>`).